# Why scala Range is not iterated during foreach?

Tags: scala, for-loop, foreach

Consider a code:

```
println("func")
println(builderFor)

private val LineCount: Int = 10000/*000*/
private val SymbolCount: Int = 100

private def builderFor: String = {
  val stBuilder = new StringBuilder()
  for (line <- 1 to LineCount) {
    for (symbol <- 1 to SymbolCount) {
        stBuilder.append("z" * symbol)
      }
  }
  stBuilder.toString()
}
```

And it prints :

```
func
```

I have replaced `stBuilder.append("z" * symbol)` with `println("ok")` and got same result. It seams that scala Range is not iterated, but why?

Comment: If I run that code in the REPL, it goes out of memory when executing builderFor. I don't suppose that is happening in your case and you are not seeing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an `App` or the body of a `def main(args: String*): Unit`, then the issue is that you call `println(builderFor)` before

```
private val LineCount: Int = 10000/*000*/
private val SymbolCount: Int = 100
```

at this pint in the code `LineCount` and `SymbolCount` are not initialized and thus `0`. Just move it two lines down.
By the way, if you want to have lines of z's, then you need to add a newline to your lines.

```
println("func")

private val LineCount: Int = 10
private val SymbolCount: Int = 10

println(builderFor)

private def builderFor: String = {
  val stBuilder = new StringBuilder()
  for (line <- 1 to LineCount) {
    for (symbol <- 1 to SymbolCount) {
      stBuilder.append("z" * symbol + "\n")
    }
  }
  stBuilder.toString()
}
```

Comment: Yep! My code is execute in `App` class. I moved `LineCount` and `SymbolCount` to the top and code became work.